# Calling applescript in R

Tags: r, applescript

Is there any way to run an applescript within R?

I found this reference in an [R FAQ on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macos/rmac-FAQ.html#SCRIPTS)

`From release 1.3.1 R has partial support for AppleScripts. This means two things: you can run applescripts from inside R using the command applescript() (see the corresponding help)`

But in my current version of R

`R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6`

neither `applescript()` nor `?applescript()` returns anything.

Thanks, Simon

Comment: You may need to use the `shell` function to call the applescript.

Answer (score 0):

Those features aren't in modern R versions (IIRC they harken back to pre-macOS/Mac OS X days).

However, the `applescript()` function performed no magic:

```
applescript <- function(script_source, extra_args = c()) {

  script_source <- paste0(script_source, collapse = "\n")

  tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".applescript")
  on.exit(unlink(tf), add=TRUE)

  cat(script_source, file = tf)

  osascript <- Sys.which("osascript")

  args <- c(extra_args, tf)

  system2(
    command = osascript,
    args = args,
    stdout = TRUE
  ) -> res

  invisible(res)

}
```

So you can do anything with it, like open a folder:

```
applescript(
  sprintf(
    'tell app "Finder" to open POSIX file "%s"',
    Sys.getenv("R_DOC_DIR")
  )
)
```

or, query an app and return data:

```
res <- applescript('
  tell application "iTunes" 
    set r_name to name of current track
    set r_artist to artist of current track
  end
  return "artist=" & r_artist & "\ntrack=" & r_name
')

print(res)
## [1] "artist=NICO Touches the Walls" "track=Hologram"
```

For (mebbe) easier usage (I say "mebbe" as the pkg relies on `reticulate` for some things) I added this to the [`macthekinfe`](https://gitlab.com/hrbrmstr/mactheknife) macOS-centric R package.

Comment: OK, I get that. But it doesn't seem to be working. The applescript I need to run in R already contains a tell and some instructions. `tell application "TextWrangler"
 activate
 replace "`

And then it's a series of replace commands. I need to run this applescript on a series of text files in a different folder.

Comment: So what doesn't work when you use that script in place of the example ones?